# Mapping between 2 json files in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, json

Which is the best method for the mapping between 2 JSON files in angularJs
I want to map beteween 2 JSON files and displayed it in my table.

JSON 1

```js
[{
    "year": 2013,  
    "doctor": "Dr. Smith", 
    "illness": "Flu", 
    "apptdate": "3/12/2013",
    "details":"Patient had flu for 5 days. No medicines prescribed"
}, {
    "year": 2014,  
    "doctor": "Dr. ram", 
    "illness": "fever", 
    "apptdate": "31/12/2014",
    "details":"Patient had flu for 5 days. No medicines prescribed"
}, {
    "year": 2015,  
    "doctor": "Dr. rom", 
    "illness": "headache", 
    "apptdate": "3/12/2015",
    "details":"Patient had flu for 5 days. No medicines prescribed"
}, {
    "year": 2016,  
    "doctor": "Dr. zen", 
    "illness": "fever", 
    "apptdate": "21/12/2016",
    "details":"Patient had flu for 5 days. No medicines prescribed"
}]
```

JSON 2

```js
[{
    "year": 2013,  
    "cost": 260
}, {
    "year": 2014,  
    "cost": 360
}, {
    "year": 2015,  
    "cost": 102
}, {
    "year": 2016,  
    "cost": 180
}]
```

I want to map these files based on the year , and displayed it in my smart-table.
Which is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: So you need to populate first json with the "cost" data for particular years?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by using `map`, `assign` and `find` :

```
function merge(json1, json2) {
    if (!json1 || !json1.length || !json2 || !json2.length) {
        return [];
    }
    return json1.map((current) => {
        return Object.assign(current, json2.find((el) => {
            return el.year === current.year;
        }));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [loadash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4):

```
var result = _.map(a, function(item) {
    return _.merge(item, _.find(b, ['year', item.year]));
});
```

By using [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map), [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) and [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge)

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2wujbd2/)</kbd>

*Output:*

```
[
  {
    "year": 2013,
    "doctor": "Dr. Smith",
    "illness": "Flu",
    "apptdate": "3/12/2013",
    "details": "Patient had flu for 5 days. No medicines prescribed",
    "cost": 260
  },
...
]
```

---

If you don't need `cost`, replace `_.merge` with `_.assign` a.e.

```
var result = _.map(a, function(item) {
    return _.assign(item, _.find(b, ['year', item.year]));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be utilised for merging two json:

```
function merge(obj) {
    var sources = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    sources.forEach(function (source) {
      for (var prop in source) {
        target[prop] = source[prop];
      }
    });
    return obj;
}

var result = merge({}, json1, json2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Merging two JSON Objects:

```
var o1 = { a: 1 };
var o2 = { b: 2 };
var o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign(o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
console.log(o1);  // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, target object itself is changed.
```

Merging with same properties:

```
var o1 = { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 };
var o2 = { b: 2, c: 2 };
var o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign({}, o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)